# invoking selected state on button makes text disappear

Tags: android, button, android-drawable

I have a simple selector that has a selected state so I can setSelected(true) on my Button and it shows it to be selected. I'm creating an ActionBar type looking thing. It works well on some android devices (nexus tablet) (v4.1.2) but on Samsung Galaxy S2 (v2.3.6) it hides the text of the button when I invoke setSeletcted(true) state. Anyone know why this could be happening?

My *button_tab_selected* and *button_tab* png image resources are both 47x47 9 patches.

**drawable_tabcontrolbutton.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_tab_selected" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_tab"/>
</selector>
```

**Layout Code**

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_draws"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/drawable_tabcontrolbutton"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:text="DRAWS"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_results"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/drawable_tabcontrolbutton"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:text="RESULTS"
    android:textSize="18sp" />
```

**Java Code**

```
    final Button button_draws = (Button) findViewById(com.tattsbet.android.R.id.button_draws);
    button_draws.setSelected(true);
    final Button button_results = (Button) findViewById(com.tattsbet.android.R.id.button_results);

    button_draws.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            button_draws.setSelected(true);
            button_results.setSelected(false);
            drawsSelected();
        }
    });
    button_results.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            button_results.setSelected(true);
            button_draws.setSelected(false);
            resultsSelected();
        }
    });
```

Comment: It might be style problem, can you define an exactly color and try. maybe white background/white text can cause.

Comment: Wow that fixed it @Mert. I just added textColor attribute to my <Button/> xml. Construct a brief answer around that and I'll give you the bounty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be a Button style problem. You should define an exact color by using the textColor attribute in your  xml. White background/white text might be the cause. 
Styles can be different phone to phone, version to version.

It's good to explicitly define all style properties to avoid these kind of problems.